# How to remove price outliers from dataset so they don't impact average price

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the bank we are using the average price from six vendors. But we now and then entcounter wrong prices due to the fact that one or more vendors some time publish an incorrect price and this affects the average price. I seek inspiration/suggestions to most effecient/correct way and which formula/logic to use to exclude these price outliers. Here below you see an example of the problem. The prices in red text are considered outliers.

[image]

Remaining challenge when only three vendors publish a price and when one of these is a outlier. How do I remove/exclude this outlier?
[image]
Note: SAND=True and FALSK= False.

Hope someone can help us out. Many thanks in advance ;-)

Kind regards

Soren Sig Mikkelsen

Comment: Take a look at the `TRIMMEAN` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution1:**

Easiest of way to remove is via defining the **inter quartile range**...

In below screenshot you can see the formulas with calculated values...

Logic is very simple, calculate the inter quartile range of your data & see if any of the 6 value is outside the upper/lower limit, If so then it's outlier...

[image]

**Solution2:**

**Using Average & Std Deviation**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Your provided solution works fine as long as at least four vendors publish a price. Please see my remaining chanllenge when only three vendors publish a price and when one of these is a outlier. How do I remove/exclude this outlier? Please see example of challenge shown in my intital question above.

Comment: @ssm78551 I've edited my answer above with one more solution (2); which seems to be working for both 3 & 6 vendors... The trick actually in both method is finding the lower/upper limits... You can basically optimize it with multiplying factor, as of now in solution2, I kept it as 1... which worked in both sample cases above...

Comment: Thanks one more time. Question herby resolved.